# cannot refresh a uitableviewcontroller after adding elements

Tags: mysql, ios, json, uitableview, uialertview

I am populating a `uitableviewcontroller` with queries from a mysql database, the initial population of the table works when starting the view. However, it is a forum type application, and after adding a comment, I have tried:

```
[self.myTableView reloadData];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

and I have tried many other solutions. Nothing seems to be working. I have an `alertview` with a textfield that is used to add a post to the database, and everything gets added, I just can't reload the `uitableviewcontroller` after adding the comment.

Comment: If you are using UITableViewController then you call it's tableview by [self.tableView reloadData] because UITableViewController already have tableView in it so you don't required to add tableView in it. So try this it will work..

Comment: try to reload with main thread